# How do I load all addons, even if I am not subscribed to it (but have it downloaded already)?

Tags: garrys-mod, steam-workshop

In Garry's Mod, there are addons; some of which are legacy (.zip files that you can download off garrysmod.com) or workshop files (anything with .gma).

I've downloaded some addons, most of which are from the workshop. On my main account, all the addons work fine and they work as per normal... However, when I switch over to my alternate (on the same computer, but different account), all my downloaded addons seems to have stopped working.

**Is there any way to force GMod to load all the addons in the *garrysmod/garrysmod/addons/...* folder? Even if you didn't subscribe to it?**
... Or subscribe automatically to them all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The unsubscribed addons will load as long as you're in offline mode** on Steam. When you're in offline mode, Steam does this wonderful thing it should always do, and forgets which addons you are subscribed to, or not; and loads every single file you have in your addons folder.

WARNING: if you have 200+ addons with a lot of custom content, you will want to remove some addons before you try and launch in offline mode because like I said Gmod will load *everything* you've ever subscribed or unsubscribed to and haven't physically deleted from the addons folder yourself.

Comment: Don't worry - The online mode addon count is already 300+. I'm sure offline mode won't make a difference :)

Answer (score 0):

You must put them in as a folder and make sure that the folder has an addon.txt file inside of it. If it does, whenever you start Garry's Mod, the addon should load.

For .gma Files:
Put those into your addons folder since subscribing to an addon just puts the GMA file into your addon folder and restart your game. OR. Use a GMAd converter to turn a folder into a .gma or a .gma into a folder.

Comment: Yes @SirMeepington, of course, that's the obvious course of action, but how do you run installed `.gma` addons to work without subscribing to them (in the workshop) in the first place.

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: Also: To point out: Don't you actually extract the files from the `.gma` and not turn a folder into a `.gma`? (Remember: An unsubscribed mod will not be loaded; all it does is take space on your Hard Disk).

Comment: I was sure that .gma files will be loaded even if you have unsubscribed, but I don't worry about these things. Hope I could help solve your problem.

Comment: Nope. They don't @SirMeepington. You need to subscribe to them to use them, even if it's already downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the gma file it should load even if your in online in gmod
To extract the gma file, go into the gmod folder and click on the bin folder, then you should find gmad, find you gma addon and drag it on the gmad icon, then it should start extracting it, you should see the extract file of where your gma file was
hope it help